# How do I associate my google OpenID to my account, if I've mistakenly created a NEW account using the Google OpenID?

Tags: support, openid, login

After reading the [Google Offers Named OpenIDs](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/11/google-offers-named-openids/) blog post, I went about creating alternate google openids for my account (myopenid) for each site (SO, MSO, SF) but while attempting to add the Google OpenID for Super User, I mistakenly created an entirely new account with a reputation of 1. Now I'm not able to associate my Google OpenID with my real account as the other account exists. How do I get rid of the account I mistakenly created, so that I can associate my Google OpenID with my primary account?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would say that you'll probably have to get a moderator or site admin to do it for you.  `team@stackoverflow.com` should get to them.

Answer (score 1):

I mistakenly created a new account while trying to add a StackExchange OpenID login.

I found that if I logged into the newly created account and deleted it I could then log back into my old account and add the new OpenID login under "my logins".